# How do I add ncmpcpp search results to the current playlist?

Tags: command-line, music-player

Using the `ncmpcpp` MPD client, in the search function (F4) how can I add all the search results to the current playlist short of adding each item one-by-one?

For example, say I search for all music where *genre == "instrumental"*. The help tells us to use <kbd>space</kbd> to add an item to the playlist, but what about the other 1,500 songs found?

I'd like to add all search results to the playlist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is <kbd>v</kbd> to reverse selection (when nothing is selected this acts as select all), then <kbd>a</kbd> to add all selected items to playlist (select current playlist from the menu that pops up).

Edit: <kbd>A</kbd> => <kbd>a</kbd>

Comment: Although this is a 3-step process: Add / current playlist / to the end - it's better than not adding any, thanks! I'd like to see if there are any other solutions for choice.

Comment: I was confused trying to use `A` (`Shift+a`), when it's `a` (i.e. lower case).

Comment: @mkaito Maybe your version has different default keys or you have a different key configuration. ncmpcpp keys can be rebound. You can look at the keys in the F1 / 1 menu.

Comment: So you mean Shift+a when you wrote A? You might want to add the shift key in your anwser then. eg <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.